# People Picker Control with Anonymous Access

Tags: active-directory, people-picker, anonymous-authentication

SP2010 Visual C# Web Part.
How can I allow Anonymous users the ability to use the People Picker control? I have already tried the typical RunWithElevatedPrivileges but continue to get 
"The control is not available because you do not have the correct permissions."

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite ElevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
    {
        using (SPWeb ElevatedWeb = ElevatedSite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
        {
            peopleEditor = new PeopleEditor();
            peopleEditor.AutoPostBack = true;
            peopleEditor.ID = "PeopleEditor1";
            peopleEditor.AllowEmpty = false;
            peopleEditor.MultiSelect = false;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(peopleEditor);
        }
    }
});
```

Is it even possible?  Thank you.

Comment: Is this a publishing site?

Comment: Aaron, did You resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible check this out:

> The solution was to grant this permission to the 'contribute'
>   permission level.

http://www.directsharepoint.com/2011/04/sharepoint-people-picker-control.html

I think thats what your asking for?

hope it helps :)

Comment: All my Permission levels already include "Browse User Information", thank you though.